# How to export candidate from Indeed Employer?

Tags: indeed

I'm trying to export my list of Indeed job candidates, however, following their help article, as well as other blogs, I seem to be missing the export button. I already enabled my 2FA but still, the button was not visible.[image]

from: https://indeed.force.com/employerSupport1/s/article/360026204071?language=en_US

> ##### To export candidates for a specific role from the Candidates Page:
>
> 1. Choose a job
> 2. Select all candidates by selecting the checkbox at the top left
> 3. Select Export Candidates

This help article indicates the same (including screenshots): https://help.wizehire.com/en/articles/2565110-how-do-i-export-candidates-from-my-indeed-account

However, when I select my job and candidates, I don't see an export button.
[image]